# Accidentally mixed orange and green antifreeze

Tags: coolant, cruze

My car has a slow coolant leak that mechanic hasn't been able to identify that takes about a year before there's an issue. It was running low and it was Christmas eve so I couldn't get Dexcool (I drive a Chevy Cruze) and ended up mixing antifreeze without realizing that that isn't a good idea.

I have plans to get the coolant flushed as a result. I'm just curious if it's a serious enough issue that I shouldn't even drive it to the mechanic (about 15 min away) or if I'll be "okay" enough to get there. Reading on the internet thus far has seen a range from "this is catastrophic" to "you don't want this to do this for too long".

It's driven about 10km, when we topped it off and returned home and arranged other travel for Christmas, and then sat for 2 days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's really unlikely that anyone has mixed coolants and then driven the same model vehicle exactly as you have, what you'll get here is opinions.

My opinion is that the additional 15 minutes' drive isn't going to be a problem. Drive it to the mechanic, make sure that after draining the cooling system the mechanic flushes the cooling system with water — maybe twice — then refills it with Dexcool.

It should be a good story with a happy ending.

Comment: Agreed. Everything I've ever read (reputable) states all these different types of coolant are mixable. The big thing is, when you mix them, you are taking away any of the longevity the OAT would give you. There is such a thing as a "HOAT" coolant, which is a hybrid between IAT (green stuff) and OAT (like Dexcool). I don't think there was any issue here for the OP.

Comment: Next time this occurs and the coolant container runs low and the antifreeze isn't available, just top it off with plain water. Diluting a 50/50 mixture with about a quart of makeup water may alter the mixture some but won't hurt the cooling system. In severe low temperature situations with a slow leak, keeping a gallon of antifreeze in the trunk avoids this situation altogether.

Comment: @FDryer I actually had just read up about this while reading about my mistake and didn't even clue in that I could have just bought some water. Definitely handy advice and I appreciate you calling it out here too!

Thanks for the help everyone. Mechanic was able to flush the system and coolant is a much more peace of mind orange instead of, well, looking literally like poop!